# QuerySyntaxException: Path expected for join! in HQL query on unrelated table

Tags: java, hibernate, hql

I have these POJO classes

```
public class MapProxy implements Serializable {

    private Service service;
    private Application application;
    private Connector connector;

    //getter and setter
}

public class CategoryTranslator implements Serializable{

    private ArtCategory artCat;
    private ProviderCategory providerCat;
    private String provider;

    //gettere and setter
}
```

I writed a query into ArtCategory xml mapper to have as result an ArtCategory from a serviceName and applicationName

here the query

```
<query name="ArtCategory.getCategoryByServApp">
    SELECT DISTINCT cat_t.artCat
    FROM CategoryTranslator cat_t 
    INNER JOIN MapProxy mp WITH (cat_t.provider = mp.connector.provider.name)
    INNER JOIN mp.service ser WITH (ser.serviceName=:serviceName)
    INNER JOIN mp.application app WITH (app.applicationName=:applicationName)
</query>
```

When I excecute this query I receve an Hibernate exception:

```
11:52:55,485 ERROR [PARSER]  Invalid path: 'mp.application'
11:52:55,499 ERROR [SessionFactoryImpl] Error in named query: ArtCategory.getCategoryByServApp
org.hibernate.hql.ast.QuerySyntaxException: Path expected for join!
```

**[UPDATE]**

This query works well:

```
SELECT DISTINCT cat_t.artCat
FROM CategoryTranslator cat_t 
WHERE cat_t.provider='test'
```

In another xml mapper (MaxProxy) I have this query which works well, too

```
<query name="MapProxy.getProxy_service_app">
    SELECT mp
    FROM MapProxy mp
    INNER JOIN mp.service srv WITH (srv.serviceName=:serviceName) 
    INNER JOIN mp.application app WITH (app.applicationName=:applicationName)   
</query>
```

Why hiberante can't map mp.application? What do I wrong?

Comment: I'm not sure, but it's not possible to JOIN two unrelated entities in HQL using arbitrary properties. CategoryTranslator and MapProxy are not related, ie. there is no reference between them.

Comment: SURE...that was the problem! this is the correct query: `SELECT DISTINCT cat_t.artCat FROM CategoryTranslator cat_t, MapProxy mp WHERE cat_t.provider = mp.connector.provider.name AND mp.service.serviceName=:serviceName AND mp.application.applicationName=:applicationName`

Comment: Nowadays you would probably change to hibernate => 5.1 which is able to support the scenario from the question.